# error accessing mysql via SSH tunnel on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh

I tried the following command

`ssh -N -L 3336:127.0.0.1:3306 [USER]@[SERVER_IP]` in my mac. I am getting the error ( Permission denied (publickey). My Macos is Catalina.

I also used Dbeaver and **tried to SSH** using the private key. I have provided
chmod 400 permission to the private key file in my .ssh folder. Still when I try to connect to mysql  via Dbeaver I am getting the error *"Specified private key cannot be converted"*. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using SSHj as an option based on the thread below worked for me.

[DBeaver ssh tunnel invalid private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979849/dbeaver-ssh-tunnel-invalid-private-key)